Need to make subfigures appear on separate pages
I am a beginner. I need to make some subfigures appear on one page and some on another. There are basically 6 subfigures and they all occupy a single page, leaving a lot of empty page on a previous page. I want two subfigures to appear on one page and 4 on another. Is there a way to do this?
I urgently need this and would appreciate any kind of help.
Thanks in advance!

Yes, and there are many exaples on this site.  First, see \ContinuedFloat (caption manual, page 21).  Also, stop using [H].

Welcome to TeX.SE. There are quite a few ways to create subfigures in a LaTeX document. Do please provide actionable information about how you go about creating subfigures.

hey everyone, thanks to everyone who responded. The \continuedfloat option worked.
